# Fiz um script que calcula a média de uma turma ou de um aluno. Mas não achei uma forma de perguntar ao user se ele quer fazer outro cálculo ou não

Tags: python

Estou iniciando em Python, então talvez isso pareça bem bobinho. Basicamente o código que fiz dá a opção de calcular a média das notas de determinada turma ou então de um aluno. Eu quero que o programa pergunte ao usuário se ele quer realizar novamente outro cálculo e de que tipo (média da turma ou média de aluno). Segue o código:

```
print('Olá!\nPara calcular a nota de um aluno, digite 1.\nPara calcular a nota de uma turma, digite 2.')
resp=str(input()); num=1; soma=0.0
while resp!='1' and resp!='2':
      resp=str(input('Sua resposta é inválida!\nPara calcular a nota de um aluno, digite 1.\nPara calcular a nota de uma turma, digite 2.\n'))

if resp=='2':
   turma=input('De qual série você deseja calcular a nota?\n')
   alunos=int(input('Quantos alunos têm a turma?\n'))
   while num<=alunos:
         print('Qual é a nota do aluno', num,'?\n')
         nota=float(input())
         soma+=nota
         num+=1
   print ('A média das notas do', turma, 'é:', soma/alunos)
else:
     if resp=='1':
        nome=str(input('Qual é o nome do aluno?\n'))
        quo=int(input('Quer saber a média de quantas provas?\n'))
        while num<=quo:
              print('Qual é a nota da prova', num, '?\n')
              notas=float(input())
              soma+=notas
              num+=1
        print('A média das notas do aluno(a)', nome, 'nas', quo, 'provas é de', soma/quo,'pontos.')
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta você fazer um *loop* para ficar repetindo o que deseja. E é interessante também ter alguma condição de saída, algo assim:

```
while True:
    # faz o que precisa (pede as notas, calcula média, etc)
    ...

    if input('Deseja continuar? S/N') == 'N':
        break # sai do while
```

Outros detalhes: [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então se quer uma string, fazer `str(input())` é redundante e desnecessário. Além disso, você pode passar a mensagem diretamente para `input`. Ou seja, em vez de:

```
print('digite algo')
s = input()
```

Faça simplesmente:

```
s = input('digite algo')
```

E para imprimir variáveis junto com a mensagem, você pode usar [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (a partir do Python 3.6). Fiz outras modificações também, ficou assim:

```
while True:
    resp = input('Olá!\nPara calcular a nota de um aluno, digite 1.\nPara calcular a nota de uma turma, digite 2.')
    soma = 0

    if resp == '2':
       turma = input('De qual série você deseja calcular a nota?\n')
       alunos = int(input('Quantos alunos têm a turma?\n'))
       for num in range(1, alunos + 1): # use um range em vez de um while
           soma += float(input(f'Qual é a nota do aluno {num}?\n'))
       print(f'A média das notas do {turma} é: {soma / alunos}')
    elif resp == '1':
            nome = input('Qual é o nome do aluno?\n')
            qtd = int(input('Quer saber a média de quantas provas?\n'))
            for num in range(1, qtd + 1):
                soma += float(input(f'Qual é a nota da prova {num}?\n'))
            print(f'A média das notas do aluno(a) {nome} nas {qtd} provas é de {soma / qtd} pontos.')
    else: # se chegou aqui, a nota não é 1 nem 2
        print('Sua resposta é inválida')

    if input('Deseja continuar? (S/N): ') == 'N':
        break # sai do while
```

---

Dá para melhorar mais, pois eu não valido se o usuário digitou "S" (apenas vejo se foi digitado "N", qualquer outra coisa faz com que o programa continue). Eu também não valido se foi digitado mesmo um número, etc. Mas a ideia básica (fazer com que o programa continue rodando) está aí.

Answer (score 1):

Simplificando e utilizando a tua base, basta um while e remover um que é desnecessário.

```
while True:
    print('Olá!\nPara calcular a nota de um aluno, digite 1.\nPara calcular a nota de uma turma, digite 2.')
    resp=str(input()); num=1; soma=0.0
    if resp not in '1' and resp not in '2':
        resp=str(input('Sua resposta é inválida!\nPara calcular a nota de um aluno, digite 1.\nPara calcular a nota de uma turma, digite 2.\n'))

    if resp in '2':
        turma=input('De qual turma você deseja calcular a nota?\n')
        alunos=int(input('Quantos alunos têm a turma?\n'))
        while num<=alunos:
                print('Qual é a nota do aluno', num,'?\n')
                nota=float(input())
                soma+=nota
                num+=1
        print ('A média das notas da turma %s é: %s' % (turma, soma/alunos))
    else:
            if resp in '1':
            nome=str(input('Qual é o nome do aluno?\n'))
            quo=int(input('Quer saber a média de quantas provas?\n'))
            while num<=quo:
                    print('Qual é a nota da prova', num, '?\n')
                    notas=float(input())
                    soma+=notas
                    num+=1
            print('A média das notas do aluno(a)', nome, 'nas', quo, 'provas é de', soma/quo,'pontos.')
```